# ASP.net : web.config import to txt or excel

Tags: asp.net, web-config

for all my Application , I need to make a document , that will contains all endpoints and database connections are used.

I was doing it manually.
is there any way , so that we can read and extract information from web.config  files.

Any idea.

Edit: 
Can it be in such a way that only required data come's up , in my case DBName and endpoints address

Answer (score 0):

web.config files are XML files, so you can take any editor capable of XML and extract the information like that.

As you mentioned Excel: Excel can open XML files as well. When I try to open a web.config I have the following choices:

[image]

After choosing "As an XML table" and having Excel generate a Schema for me I have all the web.config data in a nicely formatted Excel table.